# Login with social network and normal login IOS

Tags: authentication, social-networking, facebook-login

I develop an application IOS that requires login, but other than that classic of the app should also give the possibility to do so
via Facebook or Twitter, I would like some advice on how to manage the database, you should make a second one table where there are
all users, or a table for each different login, for example, if a user registry from my application in the table put
username, password, etc. but if I want to be a social network loggarmi recording rightly there should be, but what I post
in the database?, only your username?
For example, the application Ruzzle by you with the opportunity to enter local account with login
Facebook, I realized that doing the two login as though I've created two different users.
Usually how you handle this?